# How do I horizontally extend the clickable area of an inline span?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have two spans, both of which trigger an action when clicked:

```
<div>
    <span>This is a multiline<br/>
    chunk of text.</span>  <span>And this is a <br/>
    second one.</span>
</div>
```

I would like the user to be able to click anywhere in the containing div (which is styled to look like a box), and have the click be associated with one or the other span.   Right now, the user has to click on the actual text for the click event to get fired.

Here's what it looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/bJJLF/1/.

I want the spans to appear like a single paragraph (ie, so I probably need to keep them styled `display: inline`).  There are going to be line breaks, but I'm flexible re: how they are created (so I can kill the `</br>`s  if necessary).

Is there an easy css solution for this that I'm missing, or do I have to put a click handler on the surrounding box and do coordinate math to figure out which span the click belongs to?

Comment: I assume you want the click to be the *closest* span to the click?

Comment: To be short, yes, math it is...

Comment: @lucuma: yeah, although primarily I want it to feel intuitive to the user, so getting the matching "right" is less important than it feeling reasonable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I found a pure-css solution that seems pretty good so far.  Any suggestions on improving it would be helpful.  The main constraint right now is that you need to know the width of the containing box, which is a constraint that I can work with.

The idea is you create an absolute-positioned psuedo-before element on the spans.  You give it a  lower z-index then the span, you set its height to 100% of the span's height, set left to 0, and a width equal to the width of the container:

```
span:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
}
```

The span has to be positioned relatively:

```
span {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}
```

Here's the updated example (now with hover effects!):  http://jsfiddle.net/bJJLF/7/

Comment: You don't need the relative positioning on the span since the wrapper div is already position relative. If you remove that then you can make the :before content width 100%. http://jsfiddle.net/bJJLF/8/

Comment: Just realized that if 2 or more spans are on the same line the latest one will override any previous ones :/ Your solution is good, you could just set the width of them to be something really large and then set the div overflow to hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a little closer to your desired behavior by adding some ids to your spans so we can identify them:

```
<div>
    <span id="span1">This is a multiline<br/>
    chunk of text.</span>  <span id="span2">And this is a <br/>
    second one.</span>
</div>
```

And then change the event handler to listen to clicks on the `<div>` and then inspect the event object, which will contain a target element that the click bubbled up from:

```
$('div').click(function(e) { 
    alert($(this).text() + ' from ' + e.target.id); 
});
```

An [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bJJLF/2/).

You may want to ignore the click if it did not originate from a `<span>`:

```
$('div').click(function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'SPAN') {
        alert($(this).text() + ' from ' + e.target.id); 
    }
});
```

Another [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bJJLF/4/).

And if you only want to alert the text from the span that was clicked:

```
$('div').click(function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'SPAN') {
        alert($(e.target).text() + ' from ' + e.target.id); 
    }
});
```

One last [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bJJLF/5/).

Comment: you still need to click on the text. I don't really see wath changed in terms of functionality here. Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: right, this is useful elaboration, but it doesn't add the functionality that I'm struggling with, namely having clicks that hit the div but miss the spans be counted as hitting a span.  in my actual code, there's going to be more than two spans, and their number / content will be dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Add a handler to the outer div, and a handler to the span. When you handle the span, stop propagation so the handler for the div doesn't get called. http://jsfiddle.net/mgzke/

```
<div class="wrap">
    <span class="firstspan">This is a multiline<br/>
    chunk of text.</span>  <span>And this is a <br/>
    second one.</span>
</div>


// Using jQuery for simplicity only
$('.wrap').click(function(){
   console.log('Click in div');
});

$('.wrap .firstspan').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
   console.log('Click in spans');
});
```